# Git, Kohana & PHPFog workflow

Tags: git, kohana-3, gitattributes

Kohana 3 includes environment constants, specifically PRODUCTION, STAGING, TESTING & DEVELOPMENT ([discussion here](http://forum.kohanaframework.org/discussion/comment/38119#Comment_38119)).

It's been suggested that you set those constants using SetEnv in your .htaccess file ([discussion here](http://forum.kohanaframework.org/discussion/5482/how-to-deal-with-svn-and-kohanas-config.php/p1)).

For Example:

PRODUCTION .htaccess:

```
SetEnv KOHANA_ENV PRODUCTION
SetEnv BASE_URL http://www.domain.com
```

DEVELOPMENT .htaccess:

```
SetEnv KOHANA_ENV DEVELOPMENT
SetEnv BASE_URL http://127.0.0.1/domain/
```

I've been looking for ways to manage the different version of the .htaccess file in Git.  I looked at branching, but [VonC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6309/vonc) submitted a [great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100829/when-should-you-branch/2107672#2107672), suggesting it might not be the best approach.

VonC further suggested [.gitattributes filter driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2965060/gitignore-doesnt-ignore-files/2965233#2965233) as a solution ([Pro Git](http://progit.org/book/ch7-2.html) explanation).

I like the idea of using the .gitattributes filter driver, but I've struggled to find "how to" examples that I can understand (the Pro Git examples were a little above me).

I'm using [PHPFog](https://www.phpfog.com) to deploy. They require you to do [clone and push](http://docs.phpfog.com/index.php/features/article/getting_started_custom_application) to deploy your application.

So here are my questions:

- Is this the right approach for setting environment variables in Kohana?
- Can I use the .gitattributes filter driver with PHPFog?
- How do I create the filter to add the environment variables to the .htaccess file?

Comment: I've posted the same question to the Kohana community here: http://forum.kohanaframework.org/discussion/8582/git-kohana-phpfog-workflow

Comment: Just FYI, PHP Fog introduced environment variables to the App Console not long ago so you can set the variables from the console now.

Answer (score 1):

According to many forums out there setenv in htaccess is perfectly acceptable
--On PHPFog you can set environmental variables in the app console.

.gitattributes were not a requested feature and never made it into PHPFog

You can make the htaccess file using vi or vim aka:

`vim /.htaccess`

then use `i` to insert new data

and

`esc` to escape out

and

`:wq`

to save and exit vim